# Removing duplicates from comma-separated list

Tags: jquery, csv

I am generating a comma-separated list out of the rel-attributes of several li-elements, using the map-function.

```
poiSelectedList = $('#poiList li li.selected').map(function() { return $(this).attr('rel'); }).get().join(',');
```

How can I assure that there are no duplicates inside my list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a cache like this:

```
var cache = [];
poiSelectedList = $('#poiList li li.selected').map(function() {
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    if(cache.indexOf(rel) === -1) {
        cache.push(rel);
        return rel;
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}).filter(function(a, b) {
   return b !== undefined;
}).get().join(',');
```

---

Or, as patrick dw suggested, a more concise version:

```
var cache = [];
$('#poiList li li.selected').each(function() {
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    if(!$.inArray(rel, cache)) {
        cache.push(rel);
    }
});
var poiSelectedList = cache.join(); // defaults to ,
```

Comment: You're building an Array that holds the unique values, so you could skip the `.filter()`, `.get()`, `.join()`, and the return statements, and use an `.each()` instead of `.map()`. Although `Array.prototype.indexOf()` is lacking in some browsers. May want to change that to `$.inArray()`.

Comment: You're welcome. :o) BTW, I [filed an enhancement request](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9944) to pass the new Array being built as the 3rd argument to the callback for `$.grep` and `$.map` so that such `$.inArray` sorts of tests could be performed on the new Array itself instead of having to maintain a supplemental list.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
var duplicates = {};

poiSelectedList = $('#poiList li li.selected').map(function() { 
     var rel = $(this).attr('rel'); 
     if (duplicates[rel] !== true){
         duplicates[rel] = true;
        return rel;
   }
}).get().join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is not short nor good-looking, it should be a fast way

```
var poiSelectedList='';
var tmp;
$('#poiList li li.selected').each(function() { tmp[$(this).attr('rel')]=1; });
var comma=0;
for(var i in tmp) if (tmp.hasOwnProperty(i)){
if(comma){poiSelectedList+=','}else{comma=1}
poiSelectedList+=i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery

```
var poiSelectedList = $('#poiList li li.selected').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('rel');});
$.unique(poiSelectedList);
poiSelectedList.get().join(',');
```

Comment: $.unique only works with an array of dom-elemens. And, beside, i am already using jQuery.

Comment: True, but any real browser sorts out the difference ;) http://jsfiddle.net/ZRJe6/

Comment: Unfortunately, it has to be working on at the dark site too. Thanks anyway.